# How to correct the following error in my PHP code to display "$title" list contains?

Tags: php

- **Line 83** of the error I get and put below is from the `UssdNode.php`
  file which contains the declaration of the variable `$item=$items[$i]`
  in the `recurseMenu` method below.
- **Line 45** of the same error in the UssdTree.php file contains the
  declaration of the variable `$node=$this->treeMenu[$name];` in the
  `getNode` method below.
- **Line 94** of the same error in the `UssdNode.php` file contains the
  declaration of the variable `$title=$node->getTitle();` in the
  `recurseMenu` method below.

My method or function `recurseMenu` (in: `UssdNode.php`) normally contains **the list of menus** (***WHICH I LOOK TO DISPLAY***) contained in the variable `$title=$node->getTitle()`:

```
function recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit) {
    $objectString="<strong>". $this->getTitle() . "</strong>" . PHP_EOL;
    $lastMenu=false;
    if(count($items)>0) {
        for($i=$this->index;$i<$bufferLimit;$i++){
            $item=$items[$i];

            /* echo "<pre>";
            print_r($item);
            echo "</pre>"; */

            $num=$i+1;
            //get node by name
            $userSessions=$_SESSION['userSessions'];
            $currUserSession=$userSessions[$this->address];
            $node=$currUserSession->getNode($item);
            $title=$node->getTitle();
            $objectString=$objectString . PHP_EOL .$num . '. ' .$title;
        }
    } else {
        $objectString=$objectString.PHP_EOL . 'NO DATA AVAILABLE, TRY AGAIN LATER';
    }
    $lastMenu=$bufferLimit==count($items);
    $objectString=$objectString . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "<strong>0. Exit</strong>";
    if($this->getParent() != '0'){
        $objectString=$objectString . PHP_EOL . "<strong>#. Back</strong>";

    }
    if($lastMenu===false){
        $rem=count($items)-$this->index;
        $objectString=$objectString . PHP_EOL . "<strong>99. Next (".$rem.")</strong>";
    }
    return $objectString;
}
```

**The `getNode` method of the `UssdTree.php` file**:

```
function getNode($name){
    $node=$this->treeMenu[$name];
    return $node;
}
```

And **when I try the debug of** `$this->recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit)` in my `toString` method or function which displays the list of `$title` as strings:

```
function toString(){
    $objectString='';
    $items=$this->children;
    $bufferLimit=(count($items)==0)?1:$this->getBufferLimit()+1;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($this->recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit));
    echo "</pre>";

    do{
        $bufferLimit-=1;
        $objectString=$this->recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit);
    }while(strlen($objectString>160));
    $this->index=$bufferLimit;
    return $objectString;
}
```

The problem is that nothing is displayed. And I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in
> C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdNode.php on line 83
>
> Notice: Undefined index: in
> C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdTree.php on line 45
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTitle() on
> null in C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdNode.php:94
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdNode.php(59): UssdNode->recurseMenu(Array, 4)
> #1 C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdUserSession.php(77): UssdNode->toString()
> #2 C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdReceiver.php(51): UssdUserSession->fetchDisplay()
> #3 C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdReceiver.php(43): UssdReceiver->handleChildBearingNode('paybill', '0772247408',
> '1234567')
> #4 C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdReceiver.php(15): UssdReceiver->handleContinuingRequests('0772247408', '4', '1234567')
> #5 C:\laragon\www\ussd\receiver.php(28): UssdReceiver->onMessage(Array)
> #6 C:\laragon\www\ussd\receiver.php(36): MyUssdReceiver::process(Array)
> #7 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdNode.php on line 94
>
> URL : http://localhost/ussd/receiver.php MSISDN :

How to correctly display the list of menus represented by the variable `$title=$node->getTitle();` in the recurseMenu method below ?

Help me fix this error.

Comment: How does `getBufferLimit()` relate to the length of `$items`?

Comment: You need to fix your issues before you move forward. The first error, `undefined offset`, there is no `$items[3]`. You need to make sure the offset exists before you actually try to use it. That could be a cascading fix, but the only way to know is to test. `var_dump($items);` to see what it actually contains and what indexes there are.

Comment: Once it gets an error trying to access `$items[$i]`, all the other errors follow from that.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the index before accessing it?

```
for ($i = $this->index; $i < $bufferLimit; $i++) {
  if (isset($items[$i])){
    $item = $items[$i];
    $num = $i + 1;
    // get node by name
    $userSessions = $_SESSION['userSessions'];
    $currUserSession = $userSessions[$this->address];
    $node = $currUserSession->getNode($item);
    $title = $node->getTitle();
    $objectString .= PHP_EOL . $num . '. ' . $title;
  }
}
```

Or loop the items and check if there's more than the buffer or not

```
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
  if ($i >= $bufferLimit) {
    break;
  }
  $num = $i + 1;
  // get node by name
  $userSessions = $_SESSION['userSessions'];
  $currUserSession = $userSessions[$this->address];
  $node = $currUserSession->getNode($item);
  $title = $node->getTitle();
  $objectString .= PHP_EOL . $num . '. ' . $title;
}
```

You're trying to access a key that doesn't exist. If your items array has 3 entries and the buffer limit is something like 10, you'll get errors starting from number 3 because they don't exist in the array.

Comment: This seems like a band-aid solution. The correct solution is to fix the logic so you don't access outside the array.

Comment: To give an opinion on that I'd need to see the whole class..

Comment: I don't. If you're iterating sequentially through an array, there's no reason to expect any missing elements. If there are gaps, that's almost certainly a design problem.

Comment: In this case, my suspicion is that `$this->getBufferLimit()+1` is the wrong value for `$bufferLImit`.